# Can prescription lenses correct Chromatic Aberration?

Tags: contact-lenses, visible-optical-spectrum

Are prescription lenses available to correct chromatic aberration of the human eye?

I find the effect quite appreciable: at night, I see circular rainbows around bright street lamps, and am unable to read blue neon signs since they require significantly more 'back-focusing' (I am short-sighted).

It doesn't seem like lenses to correct chromatic aberration are a routine prescription. Why not? Are they generally available upon request?